# Duvida com Mysql e php

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Boa tarde galera, estou tentando conserta um site que eu tenho acesso da empresa antes era o PostgreSQL agora estou tentando atualizar para o mysqli, estou empacado e gostaria da ajuda de vocês:

Esta tendo o seguinte erro:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't
>   match number of parameters in prepared statement in

Dei um var_dump, apareceu esse erro!!

```
Erro na Comunicação com o Banco de Dados!object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

segue o código abaixo:

valores_contato

```
<?php

    /* Conexão com o BD */
    include("../lib/connection.php");
    $cod_contato = $_GET['contato'];

    /* Constitui a string correspondente ao SQL */    

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);

    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare ($stmt, 'SELECT id_contato, nome, assunto, ip_cad_contato, telefone, email, menssagem FROM contato WHERE WHERE id = $id'))

    /* atribui os parametros aos marcadores */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, 'issssss', $cod_contato, $nome, $assunto, $ip, $telefone, $email, $menssagem);


    /* executa a query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* atribui as variaveis de resultado */

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result ($stmt, $codigo, $nome, $assunto, $ip, $telefone, $email, $menssagem);


     /* busca o valor */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);


    /* fecha a declaração */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    include ("tabela_contato.php");

    /* Fehca a conexão com o BD */
    mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

segue abaixo:

connection.php

Comment: Edite a pergunta com o código completo e o que você esta tentando fazer.

Comment: O primeiro erro é que você esta informando menos parâmetros que o exigido pela função. O segundo erro você precisa passar o código que esta usando para analisar.

Comment: Está muito vago, amigo. Pare, pense. Elabore melhor, seja mais detalhista e aponte uma parte do código onde você esteja tendo problema. Não somente o dump.

Comment: ta aee o código Guilherme Rigotti, não entendo de programação amigo so quero conserta o site para inserir cadastros,consulta o cadastro no banco de dados!! desculpa se não coloquei o código mais acho que foi sim, ve se esta certo esse código e que posso fazer para conserta, grato!!

Comment: O erro na conexão com o BD esta provavelmente relacionado ao seu `connection.php`. Edite a pergunta com ele

Comment: @Wellingtonstz `mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, 'sssssss', $cod_contato...` O tipo para `$cod_contato`, não seria s(string), mas sim i (integer). Não? Algo como: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, 'issssss', $cod_contato...`. Nem tudo que vai pro branco é string. O id não é string.

Comment: então mais eu estou conseguindo consultar no banco de dados, acredito que não seja a connection.php não!!   pq antigamente era o PostgreSQL, so que é bem antigo o site e hj em dia  atualizou neh e eu que estou tentando passar para mysqli prepa... como posso esta inserindo os outros código que tenho e a tabela?

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti tipo consigo consultar no site normal mais, não consigo mudar para consultar varias pessoas só consigo consultar um id e tem varios id, 1,2,3.. mais só aparece o 1 para mim entendeu

Comment: @fabiano coloquei do jeito que vc passou, mais não consigo consultar as outras pessoas que cadastrou no site.. /* atribui os parametros aos marcadores */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, 'issssss', $cod_contato, $nome, $assunto, $ip, $telefone, $email, $menssagem);

Comment: @Wellingtonstz Isso por que você está passando uma Query errado. está colocando no final WHERE 1, se fosse quer consultar outros IDS você precisa passar para  Query. `WHERE id = $id` e não 1

Comment: @Wellingtonstz No seu if, abre e fecha o sinal de chave e deixe o fechar a conexão de fora do if `if(){ ...} mysqli_close($connect);`
Verifique esse `include ("tabela_contato.php");`, se deverá ficar fora ou dentro das chaves... Também atente-se ao comentário acima do @GuilhermeRigotti

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti e pq eu tinha colocado como esta no banco de dados no SQL, mais coloquei da forma que vc falo, não mudou nada..

Comment: @Wellingtonstz quando você alterar o código, altera também a pergunta para que possamos ver oq você fez. Outra coisa, retire esse `mysqli_stmt_prepare` de dentro do `IF` que ele não esta verificando nada

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro não entendi o que vc me passou.. estou tentando passa uma foto aqui de como esta mais não consigo onde posso manda uma foto da consulta!!

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti editei la na pergunta que eu fiz, mais não entendi sobre esse IF, como posso esta tirando mysqli_stmt_prepare dentro dele, estou tentando mais da erro!!

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti coloquei que vc passou, mais coloquei a tabela que vc não colocou no codigo e coloquei minha conexão normal que esta tud. mais mesmo assim sem sucesso

Comment: Você não postou seu arquivo `connection.php`. Quando for postar apenas edite sua pergunta, recomendo apagar as 2 respostas que você colocou e somente editar sua perugnta.

Comment: A respeita do erro. Está dizendo que não existe esses elementos na sua pagina. Dai precisamos descobrir se a conexão esta funcionando e depois se esses campos existem mesmo na tabela.

Comment: então mais existe sim na tabela pode fica tranquilo coloquei minha conexão mais não sei tem que ser autorizado, pq ela não foi mais foi a foto da tabela mais depois vou atualizar passando a tabela pra vc da uma olhada.. apaguei as duas resposta que vc falo!! obrigado mesmo por me ajudar deve ser coisa simples, mais pra quem não entende de programação fica difícil!

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti Bom dia, não consegui arrumar o defeito ainda, desculpa essa semana foi correria no serviço.. e no fds, dezembro só festas fooda!!

Comment: alguma ajuda???

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer seu arquivo `valores_contato` para o seguinte e veja se da certo.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "senha", "bd");

/* Verifica a conexao*/
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexão falhou: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$cod_contato = $_GET['contato'];
$id = $_GET['id']; /*Você precisar passar o ID também se quer fazer uma consulta pelo ID, isso é logico.*/


/* Cria uma declaração preparada */
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'SELECT id_contato, nome, assunto, ip_cad_contato, telefone, email, menssagem FROM contato WHERE id = ?')) {

    /* Atribui os parametros ao marcador "?" */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);

    /* executa a Query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* Atribui as variáveis de resultado */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $nome);

    /* Busca o valor */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

   var_dump($nome);

    /* fecha a declaração */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* fecha a conexão */
mysqli_close($link);
```

PS: Como você não postou seu arquivo `connection.php` eu fiz a conexão nessa pagina apenas para teste.